# How can I insert a new table row into every other row in an existing table?

Tags: sqlite, syntax, insert, modulus

Ok I have a sqlite db, that has roughly 100 rows. It is kind of a strange thing that I'm trying to do, but I need to insert a new row between each of the existing rows.

I have been trying to use the Insert statement as follows, but haven't had any luck:

```
insert into t1(column1) values("hello") where id%2 == 0
```

So I'm basically trying to use the %-operator to tell me if the id is even or odd. For every even id number, I'd like to insert a new row.

What am I missing? What can I do differently? How can I insert a new row into every other row and have the index updated as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question assumes that the rows have some kind of built-in order to them, and that you can insert rows between other rows. That's not true.

It is true that rows have an order on disk, and that the `id` column is usually assigned in order, but that's an implementation detail. When you perform a query, the database is free to return the rows in any order it chooses, unless you specify what you want with an `ORDER BY` clause.

Now, I'm assuming what you really want is to insert rows between the existing rows in `id` order. One way to get what you want would look like this:

```
UPDATE t1 SET id = id * 2
INSERT INTO t1 (id, column) SELECT id+1, "hello" FROM t1
```

The `UPDATE` would double the ids of all the existing rows (so 1,2,3 becomes 2,4,6); then the `INSERT` would perform a query on t1 and use the result to insert a new set of rows with `id` values one more than the existing rows (so 2,4,6 becomes 3,5,7).

I haven't tested the above statements, so I don't know if they would work or if they require some extra trickery (like a temporary table) since we are querying and updating the same table in one statement. Also I may have made a syntax error.

Comment: I appreciate the insight! I know that what I'm asking is unusual, I'm glad you were able to give me a solution to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't consider the rows as pre-ordered in the database. A database will store them as they come in, or according to an index. It's your task to order them on retrieval (i.e. when you query for data) according to your needs.